# Google Bar Chart With Custom Colors for Dynamic Data

Tags: java, google-visualization

I am calling a Java servlet to return data which I will display in a google chart. Here is my code:

```
    var colorPalate = ["#0d2713", "#8b9061", "#4cb274", "#898cca", "#02a4cf", "#d78e5d", "#87bd16", "#84b971", "#bacabe", "#766499", "#e51d85", "#287066", "#792b1b", "#401bec", "#0fdc3d", "#f6ade7", "#8fb4ad", "#de8456", "#16be99"];           
$.get(ajaxURL, function(responseText){
                var j = $.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(responseText));
                var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
                data.addColumn('string', 'Person');
                data.addColumn('number', 'Time');
                for( i=0;i < j.recordList.length ;i++){                      

                    data.addRows([
                        [j.recordList[i]['Affiliate'], Number(j.recordList[i]['Time'])]

                    ]);
                }
                var options = {'title':'Effort - ' + value,
                         'width':800,
                         'height':660,
                         is3D: true,
                         colors: colorPalate
                     };

                // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
                var chart;
                if($('input[name=chartType]:checked').val() == "Pie"){
                    chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
                }else{
                    chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
                }

                chart.draw(data, options);

            });
```

It works great with pie charts, I see all of the colors in colorPalate, but for bar graphs I only get the first color, supposedly because it's all in the same series.

I know I could use code like this:

```
 var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Year', 'Visitations', { role: 'style' } ],
    ['2010', 10, 'color: gray'],
    ['2020', 14, 'color: #76A7FA'],
    ['2030', 16, 'opacity: 0.2'],
    ['2040', 22, 'stroke-color: #703593; stroke-width: 4; fill-color: #C5A5CF'],
    ['2050', 28, 'stroke-color: #871B47; stroke-opacity: 0.6; stroke-width: 8; fill-color: #BC5679; fill-opacity: 0.2']
  ]);
```

But I can't make that dynamic, at least I don't know how. Other suggestions include pre-formatting the json to be inserted directly, but the way they want me to organize the json array is a bit confusing to me at the moment. Anyone know how I could make that colorPalate array be applied to a bar graph while keeping the data dynamic?

UPDATE:

I'm trying this now for the bar chart:

```
data.addColumn("string", "Group")
                    for( i=0;i < j.recordList.length ;i++){  
                        data.addColumn("number", j.recordList[i]['Affiliate']);
                    }
                    data.addRows([
                        ["Time"] 
                    ]);
                    for( i2=5;i2 < j.recordList.length ;i2++){
                        data.addRows([
                        [Number(j.recordList[i2]['Time'])] 
                    ]);
                    }
                    chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
var options = {'title':'Effort - ' + value,
                         'width':800,
                         'height':660,
                         is3D: true,
                         colors: colorPalate
                     };
                chart.draw(data, options);
```

I am getting the following error:

> Uncaught Error: Row given with size different than 15 (the number of
>   columns in the table).

Edit: Here is the row data:

["Time",468.1666666666667,266.5333333333333,158,26.25,68.98,31.25,24.25,26.29,13,94.5,3.5,4,11.25,9]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as you point out, each color in the `colors` configuration option maps to a specific series

first color = series 0,
second color = series 1, etc...

to use this option, the values must be in columns, instead of rows

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var container = document.getElementById('chart_div');
    var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(container);

    var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    dataTable.addColumn('string', 'Person');
    dataTable.addColumn('number', '2010');
    dataTable.addColumn('number', '2020');
    dataTable.addColumn('number', '2030');
    dataTable.addColumn('number', '2040');
    dataTable.addColumn('number', '2050');

    dataTable.addRows([
      ['Time', 10, 14, 16, 22, 28]
    ]);

    chart.draw(dataTable, {
      colors: ["#0d2713", "#8b9061", "#4cb274", "#898cca", "#02a4cf", "#d78e5d", "#87bd16", "#84b971", "#bacabe", "#766499", "#e51d85", "#287066", "#792b1b", "#401bec", "#0fdc3d", "#f6ade7", "#8fb4ad", "#de8456", "#16be99"],
      bar: {
        gap: 4
      }
    });
  },
  packages:['corechart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

**EDIT**

this line will cause an error because only one column is provided...

```
data.addRows([
  ["Time"] 
]);
```

same with the `for` loop, only adds one column...

```
for(i2=5; i2 < j.recordList.length; i2++){
  data.addRows([
    [Number(j.recordList[i2]['Time'])] 
  ]);
}
```

to make it easier, use a temporary array (`[]`) to build the row

then use `addRow` instead of `addRows`

see following snippet...

```
data.addColumn("string", "Group")

for(i=0; i < j.recordList.length; i++){
  data.addColumn("number", j.recordList[i]['Affiliate']);
}

var rowData = ["Time"];

for(i2=5; i2 < j.recordList.length; i2++){
  rowData.push(Number(j.recordList[i2]['Time']));
}

data.addRow(rowData);

chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
var options = {
  'title':'Effort - ' + value,
  'width':800,
  'height':660,
  is3D: true,
  colors: colorPalate
};

chart.draw(data, options);
```

**EDIT #2**

not sure i'm following correctly, in the following line...

`var j = $.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(responseText));`

if `j` is equal to...

```
["Time",468.1666666666667,266.5333333333333,158,26.25,68.98,31.25,24.25,26.29,13,94.5,3.5,4,11.25,9]
```

then see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages:['corechart']
});

function drawChart() {
  var colorPalate = ["#0d2713", "#8b9061", "#4cb274", "#898cca", "#02a4cf", "#d78e5d", "#87bd16", "#84b971", "#bacabe", "#766499", "#e51d85", "#287066", "#792b1b", "#401bec", "#0fdc3d", "#f6ade7", "#8fb4ad", "#de8456", "#16be99"];

  var j = ["Time",468.1666666666667,266.5333333333333,158,26.25,68.98,31.25,24.25,26.29,13,94.5,3.5,4,11.25,9];

  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

  for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++) {
    if (i === 0) {
      data.addColumn("string", "Group");
    } else {
      data.addColumn("number", "Column " + i); // replace with affiliate
    }
  }

  data.addRow(j);

  chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  var options = {
    'title':'Effort - ',
    'width':800,
    'height':660,
    is3D: true,
    colors: colorPalate
  };

  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

otherwise, please share the contents of `j`...

Comment: Does that come down to adding columns instead of adding rows? Oh, wait . . . I see. I have to add the column and its attribute separately. Let me give this a shot, I think I understand now.

Comment: I updated my answer, it's telling me my rows and columns aren't matching, but I'm running them in mirror for loops.

Comment: I came up with the "create a temp array" idea after reading your first example, which doesn't give me the row error, instead it gives me "Uncaught Error: Every row given must be either null or an array"

Comment: Sure, let's [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124243/discussion-between-marcel-marino-and-whitehat).

Comment: Okay, I think I know what is happening. When I use rowArray.push(Number(j.recordList[i]['Time'])); that is somehow not adding to the array, it's adding to the first item in the array. I don't know why it is doing it. It doesn't seem like that is how it should work.

Comment: So, it seems that creating a dynamic array and pushing to it creates a different object than if you hard coded the array. I took your array (var j) and then iterated through it and pushed each item to a new array, I get that number matching error. This is weird. Also, when I compare the arrays in the console they look different. The dynamic is missing the entries at the top, if that makes any sense.

Comment: Okay, I gave you the correct answer, but could you please amend your answer to include a static array? Instead of rowArray.push(value) it should be rowArray[i]  = value. That creates the array in such a manner that Google Charts can read it properly. Don't ask me why.

Comment: not sure which part to amend -- seems like the main point here is to use columns vs. rows in order to assign bar `colors` -- and you're more than welcome to edit the answer...